# Cannot start any demo Vaadin projects at IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, localhost, vaadin

everyone!

I'm newbee at vaadin and have a stupid question:
Trying to open new demo ToDo-list project according to official guide: https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/flow/guide/quick-start

But when starting at IntelliJ IDEA (ver 2022.1.1 EDU), IDE and localhost/8080 have long list of Exceptions:

```
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Sun May 29 23:09:34 MSK 2022
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
java.lang.IllegalStateException: com.vaadin.flow.server.ExecutionFailedException: Command 'npm install' failed to finish
com.vaadin.flow.server.ServiceException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: com.vaadin.flow.server.ExecutionFailedException: Command 'npm install' failed to finish
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinService.handleExceptionDuringRequest(VaadinService.java:1616)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1579)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:299)
    at com.vaadin.flow.spring.SpringServlet.service(SpringServlet.java:109)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:711)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:459)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:353)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:313)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ServletForwardingController.handleRequestInternal(ServletForwardingController.java:141)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:177)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:51)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1067)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:890)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1743)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: com.vaadin.flow.server.ExecutionFailedException: Command 'npm install' failed to finish
    at com.vaadin.base.devserver.AbstractDevServerRunner.getCause(AbstractDevServerRunner.java:769)
    at com.vaadin.base.devserver.AbstractDevServerRunner.getCause(AbstractDevServerRunner.java:765)
    at com.vaadin.base.devserver.AbstractDevServerRunner.handleRequest(AbstractDevServerRunner.java:631)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1567)
    ... 52 more
Caused by: com.vaadin.flow.server.ExecutionFailedException: Command 'npm install' failed to finish
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.frontend.TaskRunNpmInstall.runNpmInstall(TaskRunNpmInstall.java:408)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.frontend.TaskRunNpmInstall.execute(TaskRunNpmInstall.java:183)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.frontend.NodeTasks.execute(NodeTasks.java:945)
    at com.vaadin.base.devserver.startup.DevModeInitializer.runNodeTasks(DevModeInitializer.java:414)
    at com.vaadin.base.devserver.startup.DevModeInitializer.lambda$initDevModeHandler$0(DevModeInitializer.java:343)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.run(CompletableFuture.java:1804)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.exec(CompletableFuture.java:1796)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:373)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1182)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1655)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1622)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:165)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "--no-update-notifier" (in directory "C:\NewJavaProjects\TestSpace\VaadinFrameworkTest\my-todo\my-todo"): CreateProcess error=2, Не удается найти указанный файл
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1143)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1073)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.frontend.TaskRunNpmInstall.runNpmCommand(TaskRunNpmInstall.java:484)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.frontend.TaskRunNpmInstall.runNpmInstall(TaskRunNpmInstall.java:368)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, Не удается найти указанный файл
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:494)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:159)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1110)
    ... 14 more
```

What I'm doing wrong and in which way I need to see the problem solving?

There is one problem also. Maven can't recognize this plugin

```
 <!-- Runs the integration tests (*IT) after the server is started -->
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>integration-test</goal>
                                    <goal>verify</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                        <configuration>
                            <trimStackTrace>false</trimStackTrace>
                            <enableAssertions>true</enableAssertions>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
```

I tried to download it by "dependency" tag from maven repository, but int that case application failed to start.
Please, help with this problem.

Comment: The issue could be related to the available Node version (Vaadin should automatically download the correct Node, but that might have failed for some reason). Could you try Installing Node 16.15 manually from https://nodejs.org/en/?

Comment: Maybe a strict firewall is preventing the node installationI'd also suggest to try with the latest Vaadin version. Vaadin 23 should be the best option today: https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/flow/guide/quick-start

Comment: @Tarek Oraby, thank you for advice, but the problem didn't go away with the newest node.js version

Comment: @mstahv, I have the latest version of vaadin. This is not the source of problem, but thanks for firewall advice, I'll try it.

Comment: To clarify, the link you mentioned in the post is for Vaadin 14, whereas the latest version is 23 (which is available from @mstahv link, or from start.vaadin.com).

Comment: Thanks everyone for advices. The problem actually was in Node.js. 
Needed to uninstall current node version and reinstall new node package. After that the problem has gone.